# Ошибка при выводе результата на экран(появляется лишний пробел)

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Написал python скрипт который:

1. Спрашивает сколько ссылок генерировать и запоминает в `number`
2. Спрашивает длину ссылок для генерации и запоминает в `length`
3. Генерирует рандомные слова длинной задорной в `length` из букв указанных в `chars` (например **XXzd3FYOXMJQyk0sA8W4cDvWInrG1W**)
4. Перед сгенерировано словом добавляет **https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_**
5. Результат выводит на экран(по типу **https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_ BVl8UMoVl65fZl3FhD19TgHLZBcVx1**

Проблема заключается в том, что после **https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_** появляется пробел а уже потом сгенерированное слово(например https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_ BVl8UMoVl65fZl3FhD19TgHLZBcVx1, перед B появился пробел и как ссылка видна только первая часть https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_).

Вот код:

```
import random
chars='abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
number = input('◾ Укажите желаемое количество ссылок для генерации:'+ "\n")
print(' ') 
length = input('◾ Укажите длинну чека (советуем ввести 32):'+ "\n")
print(' ')
number = int(number)
length = int(length)
print(' ')
print('☑ Работа скрипта успешно завершена: ', number, ' чеков сгенерировано.')
print(' ')
for n in range(number):
    password =''
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    print('https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_',password)
print(' ')
toexit = input("Нажмите любую клавишу для завершения.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

замени

```
print('https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_',password)
```

на

```
print('https://t.me/BTC_CHANGE_BOT?start=c_' + password) # плюс вместо запятой
```